# How to get element whose onClick has been fired on click of any child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

My HTML code is similar to this:

```
<a onclick="customerDelete056b0d37(event)" id="ixnat-d26294a3"  data-id="dsddsss3226294a3">
  <i data-js="icons" id="it2ul" class="icons">
     <polyline points="21 8 21 21 3 21 3 8"></polyline>
     <rect x="1" y="3" width="22" height="5"></rect>
     <line x1="10" y1="12" x2="14" y2="12"></line>
  </i>
</a>
```

Now I want to get the `<a>` element if any of the child elements get clicked.

As `e.target` did return the element that has been click.

Suppose `<rect x="1" y="3" width="22" height="5"></rect>` got clicked.
then `e.target` will return `<rect x="1" y="3" width="22" height="5"></rect>`

But I want the element that has `onClick` associated like in this case. It will be
`<a onclick="customerDelete056b0d37(event)" id="ixnat-d26294a3"  data-id="dsddsss3226294a3">`

So I can get the `data-id` attribute of this element. (It can be some other attribute too, just wrote `data-id` as an example).

Also as I can not use the `closest` as it will not have a fixed position, nor this will always be `a` tag. It could be another tag like `button`.

How to get the element that has event handler on click of child element?

Note: None of the attribute or attribute values will be fixed. All will be dynamic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `currentTarget` for that. It refers to the element on which the event listener was set

> The currentTarget read-only property of the Event interface identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. **It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to Event.target, which identifies the element on which the event occurred and which may be its descendant**.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

### Usage

```
<a onclick="customerDelete056b0d37(event)" id="ixnat-d26294a3"  data-id="dsddsss3226294a3">
    <i data-js="icons" id="it2ul" class="icons">
        <polyline points="21 8 21 21 3 21 3 8"></polyline>
        <rect x="1" y="3" width="22" height="5"></rect>
        <line x1="10" y1="12" x2="14" y2="12"></line>
    </i>
</a>
```

And in the javascript

```
function customerDelete056b0d37(event) {
    /* This will be the a element */
    var a = event.currentTarget;

}
```

Answer (score -5):

You can send the id of `<a>` tag as argument to function `customerDelete056b0d37("ixnat-d26294a3")` and use `document.getElementById` method to get the element in the body of `customerDelete056b0d37` function.

Answer (score -5):

You can use the `closest` method with `DOMString` like `#id` or `.class` etc. Something like this:

```js
const customerDelete056b0d37 = (event) => {
  console.log(
    event.target.closest("#ixnat-d26294a3")
  );
};
```

```html
<a
  onclick="customerDelete056b0d37(event)"
  id="ixnat-d26294a3"
  data-id="dsddsss3226294a3"
>
  <i data-js="icons" id="it2ul" class="icons">
    <polyline points="21 8 21 21 3 21 3 8"></polyline>
    <rect x="1" y="3" width="22" height="5"></rect>
    <line x1="10" y1="12" x2="14" y2="12"></line>
  </i>
</a>
```

Some other approaches you can take:

1)

```js
event.target.closest('[data-id="dsddsss3226294a3"]')
```

2. 

```js
event.target.closest("[data-id]")
```

> **NOTE:** All the mention ways are not the same, but will work same for the above example.